# Python | How to parse JSON from results from AWS response?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, boto

I was trying to get the value of `VersionLabel` which is `php-v1` but my code doesn't work properly and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Could you please let me know what's wrong and how can I parse the `php-v1`?

This is my error message.

`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'`

This is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
import json

def get_label():
   try:
      env_name = 'my-env'
      eb = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk')
      response = eb.describe_instances_health(
         EnvironmentName=env_name,
         AttributeNames=[
            'Deployment'
         ]
      )
      #print(response)
      data = json.loads(response)
      print(data['VersionLabel'])
   except:
      raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
   get_label()
```

This is the response I got from AWS when `print(response)` is invoked.

```
{
   'InstanceHealthList':[  
      {  
         'InstanceId':'i-12345678',
         'Deployment':{  
            'DeploymentId':2,
            'DeploymentTime':datetime.datetime(2016,
            9,
            29,
            4,
            29,
            26,
            tzinfo=tzutc()),
            'Status':'Deployed',
            'VersionLabel':'php-v1'
         }
      }
   ],
   'ResponseMetadata':{  
      'HTTPStatusCode':200,
      'RequestId':'12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012',
      'RetryAttempts':0,
      'HTTPHeaders':{  
         'content-length':'665',
         'content-type':'text/xml',
         'date':'Sat, 01 Oct 2016 11:04:56 GMT',
         'x-amzn-requestid':'12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012'
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm not a boto3 user but it appears that the json decode has already been done for you. Does the `dict` in `response` look right to you?

Comment: If your `print(response)` is saying such things as `datetime.datetime` and using single quotes (illegal in JSON), it definitely converted it for you already.

Comment: Try commenting out `#data = json.loads(response)` and add this line instead: `print(response['InstanceHealthList'][0]['Deployment']['VersionLabel'])`. Does this give you the desired result?

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for checking! So meaning I have to stop using json module? How can I get the value of the VersionLabel?

Comment: @BB 's suggestion should do it.

Comment: @BB Cool! Works fine now! Thanks! I'd like to thank tdelaney and NickT as well for checking!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the boto3 docs [http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html?highlight=describe_instances_health#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.describe_instances_health], the describe_instances_health method returns dict and not json. Hence, there is no need for you to do the conversion. 
To get VersionLabel from data, use -

```
data ['InstanceHealthList'][0]['Deployment']['VersionLabel']
```

Edit : Note that the above fetches the VersionLabel for the first instance, out of possible multiple instances. In case you have multiple instances and they happen to have different values of VersionLabel, then you would require additional logic to get the one you need.

Comment: Thumbs-down for AWS Responses having such deep nesting...

Answer (score 5):

just incase the ask is to convert the boto response into a legal json format -

```
import json
response_json = json.dumps(response, default=str))
```

datetime.datetime needs to be handled during the dict to json conversion